# Select an option based on text in drop-down with Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk, browser-testing

I want to choose a drop-down option based on its text,what should i do? 
This is my Html code :

```
<select name="category">
   <option>Appliances</option>
   <option>Sporting Goods</option>
   <option>Cosmetics</option>
</select>
```

And this is my selector in dusk :

```
->select('category','Appliances')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use XPath:

```php
$selector = "//select[@name='category']/option[text()='Appliances']";
$browser->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath($selector))->click();
```

Answer (score 1):

> To select a value in a dropdown selection box, you may use the select method. Like the type method, the select method does not require a full CSS selector. When passing a value to the  select method, you should pass the underlying option value instead of the display text:

So give a value to your select fields.

```
<select name="category">
   <option value="Appliances">Appliances</option>
   <option value="Sporting Goods">Sporting Goods</option>
   <option value="Cosmetics">Cosmetics</option>
</select>
```

Then use

```
->select('category','Appliances')
```

Comment: values  are dynamic. Because of this, I can not assign based on values, is there another way?

Comment: @Mahsakia-rad post your dynamic views

Answer (score -1):

```
<select class="form-select" name="product_category_id_productList_add" id="product_category_id_productList_add">
     <option value="" disabled selected>-- Select Product Category --</option>
       @foreach($product_category_data as $data)
        <option value="{{$data->id}}">{{$data->name}}</option>
       @endforeach
</select>
```

```
->select('product_category_id_productList_add', '11')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seems like the thread owner doesn't have control about how the select is created.