# How to fix dusk $browser->select() with String value

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-dusk, browser-testing

I have a filter and one option is to choose a device-type. There is a list of possible options and you can only use one of the options (so no plain text)

The filter-field is named typ_id and can be accessed with

```
$browser->select('type_id')
```

The variable which I want to use is called

```
$type_id = "Laptop"
```

So my first try was

```
$browser->select('type_id',$type_id)
```

but this does not work.

So just to check I used

```
$browser->select('type_id',1)
```

this works but is not an option as I want to use the String "Laptop" to choose the type.

This is a screenshot of the filter and the type html code:

[Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0je0t.png)

How can I use "Laptop" (or $type_id) to choose the Laptop option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select an option based on text in drop-down with Laravel Dusk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082201/select-an-option-based-on-text-in-drop-down-with-laravel-dusk)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are interpreting the use of `select(selectTagId, optionValue)` incorrectly.

Your code works when you do `select('type_id',1)` because you are using the correct option value, and it does not work when you use `select('type_id', 'Laptop')` because "Laptop" is the **Display** text and not the option value.

so if you want to use `select('type_id','Laptop')`, you should update your option tags from `<option value=1>` to `<option value="Laptop">`